# Bootstrap4 Accordion - Collapse All without use of JavaScript

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, accordion

Here is a code snippet from the Bootstrap4 documentation found at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement a similar Collapse/Expand All functionality in my Bootstrap accordion. I have found that this implementation does not work how I intended it to. This simply changes the state of the panels to the opposite of what it currently is.

For example:

*Panel1: Hidden*

*Panel2: Hidden*

*Panel3: Hidden*

becomes

*Panel1: Visible*

*Panel2: Visible*

*Panel3: Visible*

which is fine but say for example the states are like this:

*Panel1: Hidden*

*Panel2: Visible*

*Panel3: Hidden*

I would expect Collapse/Expand All to either make them all hidden or all visible but it actually becomes:

*Panel1: Visible*

*Panel2: Hidden*

*Panel3: Visible*

Is there a way using Bootstrap4 that I can toggle all panels either on or off?

E:

So if all of my panels to be collapsed have class="multi-collapse", I can collapse them with data-target=".multi-collapse" in my toggle button.

When the panel is collapsed its class is "multi-collapse collapse" and when its visible the class is "multi-collapse collapse show". If I can specify multiple classes for data-target I can make the target EITHER multi-collapse collapse or multi-collapse collapse show depending on a condition... Is there any way I can specify multiple classes for data-target?

Even if there were a way to just collapse every panel in the accordion that would do the trick.

E2:

Got it to do exactly what I wanted thanks to Zim

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="allExpanded ? '.multi-collapse:not(.show)': '.multi-collapse.show'" (click)="allExpanded = !allExpanded" [attr.value]="allExpanded ? 'Collapse All': 'Expand All'" >
```

This is an Angular project so I was able to keep track of the state of a single button using a boolean variable in the Component file.

Comment: For second scenario, hidden-visible-hidden, how would you identify wether you want to do collapse/expand?

Comment: I just updated the post with my idea on how to do that though it may not work since "multi-collapse collapse" is a subset of "multi-collapse collapse show". Meaning if the target is "multi-collapse collapse" it may also change the state of "multi-collapse collapse show"

Comment: This will be a long code (but easy) to write. If you want a lead then I can write all steps of how it can be done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way *without using JavaScript* is to have 2 separate buttons. The `data-target` would target only open `.multi-collapse.show`, or closed `.multi-collapse:not(.show)` panels..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse:not(.show)">Show all</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse.show">Hide all</button>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/uZ7UYaWEpK)

In order to do this with a single button you'd need JS to keep track of the state of the Collapse panels.

Comment: You sir are my hero this is exactly what I needed! I also managed to get it to work with just one single button by doing this:            
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="allExpanded ? '.multi-collapse:not(.show)': '.multi-collapse.show'" (click)="allExpanded = !allExpanded" >Expand/Collapse All </button> 
` where allExpanded is variable in my Angular Component

Comment: You're welcome! yes that single button works because you're using a JS framework.